# How to solve getting auto cropped image problem in Android with a custom camera?

Tags: android

I'm working on custom camera in Android. I used android.hardware.camera, when I capture image like this:

[image]

But when I display on imageview getting auto cropped image like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLhJh.jpg)

And my code is:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class CameraActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PictureCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public static final String EXTRA_CAMERA_DATA = "camera_data";

    private static final String KEY_IS_CAPTURING = "is_capturing";

    private Camera mCamera;
    private ImageView mCameraImage;
    private SurfaceView mCameraPreview;
    private Button mCaptureImageButton;
    private byte[] mCameraData;
    private boolean mIsCapturing;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.d("tag", "height oncreaate============= " + height + "width " + width);


        mCameraImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_image_view);
        mCameraImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mCameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
        final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = mCameraPreview.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mCaptureImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_image_button);
        mCaptureImageButton.setOnClickListener(mCaptureImageButtonClickListener);

        final Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(mDoneButtonClickListener);

        mIsCapturing = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_CAPTURING, mIsCapturing);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        mIsCapturing = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_CAPTURING, mCameraData == null);
        if (mCameraData != null) {
            setupImageDisplay();
        } else {
            setupImageCapture();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mCamera == null) {
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder());
                if (mIsCapturing) {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Unable to open camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mCaptureImageButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            captureImage();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener mRecaptureImageButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setupImageCapture();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener mDoneButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCameraData != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CAMERA_DATA, mCameraData);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            } else {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mCamera != null) {

            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        mCameraData = data;
        setupImageDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                if (mIsCapturing) {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to start camera preview.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    private void captureImage() {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    private void setupImageCapture() {
        mCameraImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mCameraPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCaptureImageButton.setText(R.string.capture_image);
        mCaptureImageButton.setOnClickListener(mCaptureImageButtonClickListener);
    }

    private void setupImageDisplay() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.d("tag", "height " + height + "width " + width);
        BitmapFactory.Options scalingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        scalingOptions.inSampleSize = 5;
        final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mCameraData, 0, mCameraData.length, scalingOptions);

        mCameraImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCameraPreview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mCameraImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCaptureImageButton.setText(R.string.recapture_image);
        mCaptureImageButton.setOnClickListener(mRecaptureImageButtonClickListener);
    }

}
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/capturing_image" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/preview_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/capture_image_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/capture_image" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/done" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

im also try

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = prCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size bestSize = null;
        prSupportedPreviewSizes =parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mSupportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        bestSize = prSupportedPreviewSizes.get(0);
        for(int i = 1; i < prSupportedPreviewSizes.size(); i++){
            if((prSupportedPreviewSizes.get(i).width * prSupportedPreviewSizes.get(i).height) > (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)){
                bestSize = prSupportedPreviewSizes.get(i);
            }
        }



        List<Integer> supportedPreviewFormats =  parameters.getSupportedPreviewFormats();
        Iterator<Integer> supportedPreviewFormatsIterator = supportedPreviewFormats.iterator();
        while(supportedPreviewFormatsIterator.hasNext()){
            Integer previewFormat =supportedPreviewFormatsIterator.next();
            if (previewFormat == ImageFormat.YV12) {
                parameters.setPreviewFormat(previewFormat);
            }
        }

        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        int w = 0, h = 0;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (size.width > w || size.height > h) {
                w = size.width;
                h = size.height;
            }

        }


        parameters.setPreviewSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);

        parameters.setPictureSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(w, h);
        parameters.setJpegQuality(100);


        // Set the camera to Auto Flash mode.
        if (mSupportedFlashModes != null && mSupportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)){

            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
            prCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

But I am getting same result.

Comment: have you tried setting scale type to fitXY?

Comment: yes,i tried but not working....

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScaleType in `ImageView`:

> ImageView.ScaleType   CENTER_INSIDE

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />
```

[ImageView ScaleTypes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType)

Comment: thanks for reply...i used ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE but facing same problem...always display cropped image...i try many tricks but no works..any other suggestion....